# My URL parameters are not showing

Tags: php

i have a checkout button that only displays when a certain amount has been met in the shopping cart, this works perfectly.

However, when the checkout button is pressed it is meant to redirect to a page with a url parameter such as **checkout.php?rest_id =  &Postcode =**. As this is what is specified however, i just notified a lot of my code was not working on the checkout page, when identifying the problem, i found the url for the checkout page is ....checkout.php?. There is nothing else being shown not even the rest_id= or Postcode = .

I was hoping someone on here has had a similar issue and could help me to resolve my issue.

**Code**

```
   if ($sub_total >= $minord) {
        echo"<form action='checkout.php?rest_id=" . $_SESSION['rest_id'] . "&Postcode=" . $user_pcode . "'>
<input id='check' class='checkout' type='submit' value='checkout'>
</form>";
```

The $variables have all been defined, they also have values as it been tested. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You missed the closing `'` on your action attribute. always do a 'view source' in your browser to see WHAT you generated/sent out...

Comment: Also, store the generated url into a  variable and `var_dump` it before you output it when there are issues. That way you can check it before the `echo.` easily.

Comment: @MarcB thank you, but unfortunately thats did not resolve my issue

Comment: @RyanVincent thank you i will do that now

Comment: @RyanVincent its the form action, i don't think it likes of accepts url parameter, i copy and pasted the same url into a href and it works